# Isolating an element from AJAX data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to extract an element (or rather its children) from an AJAX call, but am having difficulty isolating it. My code is as follows:

```
function AJAXcomplete(data){
    var result = $(data).find('#productDetails > *');
    jQ('#productDetails').append(result);
};

function getDetails(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var addy = jQ(this).attr("href");
    jQ('body').append('<div id="productDetails"></div>');
    jQ('#productDetails').show();
    $.get(addy, AJAXcomplete);
};

jQ('#slides').on('click', '.slideLink', getDetails);
```

The above *should* store the children of `#productDetails` from the AJAX call, and append them to a newly created div of the same id.

I can successfully retrieve the entire AJAX data and append that (tested) but I can't get the element(s) I want - nothing is selected. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if `#productDetails` is at root level of html returned( ie no wrapping body tag or other parent elements), try `filter()` instead of `find()`. SHow sample of html structure returned in ajax

Comment: please show a sample of the AJAX data

Comment: `#productDetails` isn't at root level, but using `filter()` did seem to work, although not with the wildcard child selector.

Comment: `var result = $(data).filter('#productDetails').children();` Now yields the desired result.

Comment: If that works, `#productDetails` is at root level, and there is absolutely no way that `$('<div />').append(data).find('#productDetails').children();` would'nt work as well, as it's the same thing. It appends the data to a container to avoid the problem of root level elements when using `find()` ?

Comment: I must've misunderstood then. I checked through the AJAX data and the body and head tags are somehow stripped - but the target element ordinarily resides in a body tag. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: The browser will automatically strip those tags when loaded with ajax.